# Musée d'Orsay renovation of Impressionist Gallery

Tags: paris, museums

According to the [official website](http://www.musee-orsay.fr/en), the Musée d'Orsay in Paris is renovating the Impressionist Gallery from 13 to 23 November 2018. Does someone know what that means? What does exactly the "Impressionist Gallery" refer to? Are the most famous artworks usually displayed in that room?

Comment: Just to make sure: Are you familiar with [Impressionism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impressionism)? Or are you looking for a more specific description of which paintings will and will not be available. Orsay is certainly famous for its Impressionist paintings collection and many famous artworks won't be visible during the renovation.

Comment: I understand that Orsay is known for Impressionist artworks, but I was kind of hoping that there are still some parts of the museum that are open to the public during the renovation :) I was indeed wondering whether the "Impressionist Gallery" was a specific area of the museums, i.e., so that I can figure out which paintings I'll miss.

Comment: Fair enough, I was not sure what you meant. The museum is indeed open to the public but it's been too long since I have been there to comment on which painting is located where.

Comment: This doesn't seem enough to add an answer, but most of the 5th floor galleries are closed (salle fermée on the interactive floor plan). I noticed that it includes Degas' girl dancer sculpture for one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I visited the Musée d'Orsay in October of this year. It's a large museum with three floors of public exhibits wrapping around a central atrium. It's not the "Impressionist Gallery" it's the "Impressionist Galleries" (plural). It consists of several rooms on one side of the fifth floor. These are closed off, but a selection of the most famous impressionist pieces are are temporarily on exhibit on the other side of the fifth floor.

The other floors are mostly unaffected. My wife and I spent essentially all day there and certainly didn't see everything, despite the closure. If all you want to see is Cézanne, you might be disappointed, but if you are interested in Van Gough, Gaughin, Rodin, Lautrec, or anybody but the impressionists, there is plenty to see.

Answer (score 2):

It means that the collection of Impressionist artworks normally on display in the gallery will not be accessible during the period stated. http://www.musee-orsay.fr/en/events/renovation-of-rooms.html There is a list of the works in the collection here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mus%C3%A9e_d%27Orsay

Comment: Thanks for the reference. However, it is not clear to me which paintings are part of the Impressionist gallery. Only the 9 artworks included in the link you sent?

Comment: @mgiordi The [Musée d'Orsay web site](http://www.musee-orsay.fr/en/collections/overview.html) can guide you through the collections.

Comment: @Giorgio I didn't find the museum website terribly helpful to figure out precisely what was located where.